# Explanatory variables when classifying multivariate time series data using decision trees in seglearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, graphviz, decision-tree

I am currently working on classifying multivariate time series data.
https://dmbee.github.io/seglearn/auto_examples/plot_scoring.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-scoring-py
As a reference, I replaced the RandomForestClassifier with DecisionTreeClassifier, and it worked.
But if I visualize this using export_graphviz (), **what does the feature_names parameter mean?**

Since it is time-series data, does it mean the position information of the time-series data?
However, the input data is (50, 375, 18) three-dimensional data. The length of the time series data is 375 and has the values of 18 sensors. In this example, 50 input batches are used.